# hosting Django application on Apache

Tags: python, django, apache

I'm following a tutorial on hosting Django application on Apache, and I'm new to these types of server error.

I modified the apache config file to communicate with the wsgi of my application using the following code:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/adwy/appdata/local/programs/python/python35/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp35-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIScriptAlias / "D:/Backup/Learning Python/Organized and important file/Learning files and sheets/Django_ Learning_ 1/weblog_app/weblog_app/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonHome "C:/Users/Adwy/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35"
WSGIPythonPath "D:/Backup/Learning Python/Organized and important file/Learning files and sheets/Django_ Learning_ 1/weblog_app/weblog_app"

Alias /static/ C:/Users/Adwy/Adwy/Django_ Learning_ 1/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin\static

Alias /templates/ C:/Users/Adwy/Adwy/Django_ Learning_ 1/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates

<Directory C:/Users/Adwy/Adwy/Django_ Learning_ 1/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory C:/Users/Adwy/Adwy/Django_ Learning_ 1/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "D:/Backup/Learning Python/Organized and important file/Learning files and sheets/Django_ Learning_ 1/weblog_app/weblog_app">
   <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
   </Files>
</Directory>
```

-- Now I restarted my apache  server, and run the Django server in parallel, I get Error 500,

here I copy below the logs of the Error from the Apache server:

```
[Sat Apr 04 18:41:05.681919 2020] [wsgi:warn] [pid 8608:tid 288] (70008)Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete: mod_wsgi (pid=8608): Unable to stat Python home C:/Users/Adwy/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35. Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path and access permissions for whole of the path.
 [Sat Apr 04 18:41:05.725921 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8608:tid 288] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Sat Apr 04 18:41:05.780924 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8608:tid 1780] [client 192.168.2.130:49438] mod_wsgi (pid=8608): Failed to exec Python script file 'D:/Backup/Learning Python/Organized and important file/Learning files and sheets/Django_ Learning_ 1/weblog_app/weblog_app/wsgi.py'.
[Sat Apr 04 18:41:05.780924 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8608:tid 1780] [client 192.168.2.130:49438] mod_wsgi (pid=8608): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'D:/Backup/Learning Python/Organized and important file/Learning files and sheets/Django_ Learning_ 1/weblog_app/weblog_app/wsgi.py'.
[Sat Apr 04 18:41:05.780924 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8608:tid 1780] [client 192.168.2.130:49438] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Sat Apr 04 18:41:05.780924 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8608:tid 1780] [client 192.168.2.130:49438]   File "D:/Backup/Learning Python/Organized and important file/Learning files and sheets/Django_ Learning_ 1/weblog_app/weblog_app/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>\r
[Sat Apr 04 18:41:05.780924 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8608:tid 1780] [client 192.168.2.130:49438]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application\r
[Sat Apr 04 18:41:05.780924 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8608:tid 1780] [client 192.168.2.130:49438] ImportError: No module named 'django'\r
[Sat Apr 04 18:41:05.781924 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8608:tid 1772] [client 192.168.2.130:49439] mod_wsgi (pid=8608): Failed to exec Python script file 'D:/Backup/Learning Python/Organized and important file/Learning files and sheets/Django_ Learning_ 1/weblog_app/weblog_app/wsgi.py'.
[Sat Apr 04 18:41:05.781924 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8608:tid 1772] [client 192.168.2.130:49439] mod_wsgi (pid=8608): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'D:/Backup/Learning Python/Organized and important file/Learning files and sheets/Django_ Learning_ 1/weblog_app/weblog_app/wsgi.py'.
[Sat Apr 04 18:41:05.781924 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8608:tid 1772] [client 192.168.2.130:49439] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Sat Apr 04 18:41:05.781924 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8608:tid 1772] [client 192.168.2.130:49439]   File "D:/Backup/Learning Python/Organized and important file/Learning files and sheets/Django_ Learning_ 1/weblog_app/weblog_app/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>\r
[Sat Apr 04 18:41:05.781924 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8608:tid 1772] [client 192.168.2.130:49439]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application\r
[Sat Apr 04 18:41:05.781924 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8608:tid 1772] [client 192.168.2.130:49439] ImportError: No module named 'django'\r
[Sat Apr 04 18:41:05.818927 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8608:tid 1772] [client 192.168.2.130:49441] mod_wsgi (pid=8608): Failed to exec Python script file 'D:/Backup/Learning Python/Organized and important file/Learning files and sheets/Django_ Learning_ 1/weblog_app/weblog_app/wsgi.py'., referer: http://192.168.2.130/
[Sat Apr 04 18:41:05.818927 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8608:tid 1772] [client 192.168.2.130:49441] mod_wsgi (pid=8608): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'D:/Backup/Learning Python/Organized and important file/Learning files and sheets/Django_ Learning_ 1/weblog_app/weblog_app/wsgi.py'., referer: http://192.168.2.130/
[Sat Apr 04 18:41:05.818927 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8608:tid 1772] [client 192.168.2.130:49441] Traceback (most recent call last):\r, referer: http://192.168.2.130/
[Sat Apr 04 18:41:05.818927 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8608:tid 1772] [client 192.168.2.130:49441]   File "D:/Backup/Learning Python/Organized and important file/Learning files and sheets/Django_ Learning_ 1/weblog_app/weblog_app/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>\r, referer: http://192.168.2.130/
[Sat Apr 04 18:41:05.818927 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8608:tid 1772] [client 192.168.2.130:49441]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application\r, referer: http://192.168.2.130/
[Sat Apr 04 18:41:05.818927 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 8608:tid 1772] [client 192.168.2.130:49441] ImportError: No module named 'django'\r, referer: http://192.168.2.130/
```

The main message of the server error was:

```
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.
```

I hope I can get this server running,

thanks ,,

Comment: Your python environment you're running django with doesn't have django installed. Try to run pip install django

Comment: thanks David, I reinstalled Django again, and re-started everything. However, I still get the same error! - I really don't understand where is the problem

Comment: I think here there is a major and repeated wsgiError in the logs of the server , but I can't figure out the problem